# Creating thumbnail of a portrait pdf in iphone

Tags: ios, pdf

I am new in iPhone programming. In my application I display the thumbnails of first page of the PDFs stored in my resource folder. I am using the following code to create the thumbnails, and it works good for landscape PDFs. But while creating thumbnail of portrait PDF, i am getting an image with some extra portions, which i cant see when open the PDF in a webview.

*This is the code i am using to create thumbnail:*

> NSURL* pdfFileUrl=[NSURLfileURLWithPath:filePath];
>     CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);

```
            CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();                    

            CGContextSaveGState(context);                
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(aRect.origin.x), -(aRect.origin.y));

            CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
            CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);            

            //Grab the first PDF page
            CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
            CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, aRect, 0, false);
            // And apply the transform.
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);            
            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

            // Create the new UIImage from the context
            UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            CGContextRestoreGState(context);          
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
            CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
```

While creating thumbnail image of a portrait PDF using this code, the image i am getting is not the exact one. It has some extra portions. which i think, is some hidden part of that PDF. Also when I load the same PDF in a UIWebView, i can view the correct PDF without the extra portions. Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is in taking the CGRect. I had hardcoded the rect with iPad alignments. Actually we have to take rectangle of the PDF page we are using. So I used the following changes in my code to make the correct thumbnail image of PDF.

> CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);//Grab the first PDF page
>
> CGRect aRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);//get the rectangle of the pdf page associated with the type of box(kCGPDFCropBox)